# rsync only *.php files

Tags: rsync

How can I rsync mirror only *.php files?  This gives me a bunch of empty dirs too and I don't want those.

```
rsync -v -aze 'ssh ' \
--numeric-ids \
--delete \
--include '*/' \
--exclude '*' \
--include '*.php' \
user@site.com:/home/www/domain.com \
/Volumes/Servers/
```

Comment: Didn't my answer solve your problem?

Comment: the trick is to also add ` --prune-empty-dirs \ ` to the list of arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The culprit here is  the

```
--include '*/'
```

When including a wildcard followed by the trailing forward-slash you're telling rsync to transfer all files ending with a '/' (that is, all directories).
Thus,

```
rsync -v -aze 'ssh ' \
--numeric-ids \
--delete \
--exclude '*' \
--include '*.php' \
user@site.com:/home/www/domain.com \
/Volumes/Servers/
```

If you were using that because you intend to recursively find all .php files, you’d have to use the ** wildcard.
That is,
    `--include '**/*.php'`

Another way ( http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1481/rsync-find ) is pre-finding the target files and then using rsync,

```
find source -name "*.php" -print0 | rsync -av --files-from=- --from0 ./ ./destination/
```

Comment: The rsync command excluded all files, so nothing was transferred.  I think what I did was use the original block I tried, and just ran a find command to delete all empty folders when it finished.

Comment: Yeah, the catch-all `exclude` should come after the `include`.

Comment: @G-Wiz Well I wish the answer actually said that - although I can't get it to work either way.